# Extracting the hour from a date

Tags: r

I have a date in a semi-odd format. It's written like:

```
Tue Oct 11 20:56:33 +0000 2016
```

The date is a string. The date shows what time and day a tweet was sent as in a data set. I want to find what hour each of my tweets were sent out. What is the best way to work with this? Is there a way to convert it to a date type easily, or is there a way to work with that string with what I want to do? Obviously I'd like to something like:

```
format(strptime(testTweets$Date, format = "%m %d %H:%M%S %Y", "%H"))
```

But I'm not sure how to work with the day of the week or the +0000. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `format = "%a %b %d %T %z %Y"`.  See `?strptime` under `%z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above comment beat me to it, but try the following code:

```
strptime(x, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")

[1] "2016-10-11 20:56:33"
```

You only need to check the documentation for `strptime` to figure out the correct format mask to use:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/strptime

Comment: Your code gives me an error with it:

Warning message:
In strptime(testTweets$Tdate, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y",  :
  unknown timezone '%H'

Any idea why?

Comment: @ZackVlliet I suspect the problem is with your data.  I tested my code against the one piece of input you gave us, and it worked.

Comment: Interesting. I'll see what if I can figure out what my problem is then. Thanks

Comment: If you can give me examples where my answer is not working, maybe I can debug and help you.

Comment: Still not right mate - comma is in wrong spot - I think the output will just be the hour too rather than the full date.

Comment: @thelatemail `I want to find what hour each of my tweets were sent out.`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I was just pointing out that `format(..., "%H")` as in your answer doesn't return a full date as shown.

Comment: Hence it seems that always adding a demo is not overkill, not at all.